# Install apk on android phone with C# using xamarin?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin

im working on a app coded in C#. Also im using Visual Studio XAMARIN and my android phone for that.

I want to install a apk programmatically. I download a apk from web programmatically (solved yesterday with the help here) and now i try to install the apk file. I found this: [Android: install .apk programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically)

But this is in Java and i cant use java for my Application. i tried to do it like there in C# but failed.

This is the code i tried to use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(newFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

but i cant use things like uri.fromFile etc. 
Also (im not sure where it was) i read that someone said its not even possible to do it in C# and now i dont know what to belive.

Comment: The code is correct, for uri.fromFile simply use Android.Net.Uri.FromFile.

Comment: Also use Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory

Answer (score 0):

I used the following:-

```
        Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ActionView).SetDataAndType(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + "/download/" + filename)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        promptInstall.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(promptInstall);
```

However, since updating api to 28 (Android 9.0) this no longer works and I'm looking for a solution myself....